# Pods are getting killed and recreated stating - OutOfephemeral-storage?

Tags: kubernetes

My Pods are getting killed and recreated stating that OutOfephemeral-storage

Pod describe showing below message

```
Message: Pod Node didn't have enough resource: ephemeral-storage, requested: 53687091200, used: 0, capacity: 0
```

Node Capacity

```
Capacity:
 cpu:                80
 ephemeral-storage:  1845262880Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             790964944Ki
 nvidia.com/gpu:     8
 pods:               110
Allocatable:
 cpu:                79900m
 ephemeral-storage:  1700594267393
 hugepages-1Gi:      0
 hugepages-2Mi:      0
 memory:             790612544Ki
 nvidia.com/gpu:     8
 pods:               110
```

node disk usage

```
]$ df -h 
Filesystem                                                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                                                       1.7T   25G  1.7T   2% /
devtmpfs                                                        378G     0  378G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                           378G   16K  378G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                           378G  3.8M  378G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                           378G     0  378G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Still, the pod is getting rescheduled after some time? any thought why?

Comment: Hi, Could you check the logs of kubelet, what does it say ?

Comment: kubelet: I0411 19:00:03.831380   78181 predicate.go:137] Predicate failed on Pod: lXXXXXX Node didn't have enough resource: ephemeral-storage, requested: 53687091200, used: 0, capacity: 0

Comment: Can you provide some yaml config files? Some reproducible example?

Comment: we have added `ephemeral-storage:`  in resources limits: and requests: session.(10GB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the filesystem, solved with help of the following steps

```
]# systemctl stop kubelet
]# systemctl stop docker
]# umount -l /<MountFolder>
]# fsck -y /dev/sdb1
]# init 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In most  cases, this is happening due to excess of log messages are consuming the storage. Solution for that would be to configure the [Docker logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/)  to limit the amount of saved logs:

```
{
"log-driver": "json-file",
"log-opts": {
"max-size": "100m",
"max-file": "10"
}
}
```

Also worth to mention Docker takes a conservative approach to cleaning up unused objects (often referred to as “garbage collection”), such as images, containers, volumes, and networks: these objects are generally not removed unless you explicitly ask Docker to do so. This can cause Docker to use extra disk space.
It helped for me to use docker function called  `prune`. This will clean up the system from unused objects. If you wish to cleanup multiple objects you can use  `docker system prune`. Check here more about  [prunning](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/).

Next possible scenario is that that there are pods that use emptyDir without storage quotas. This will fill up the storage. The solution for this would be to set quota to [limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#requests-and-limits-setting-for-local-ephemeral-storage) this:

```yaml
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
      limits:
        ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
```

Without this being set any container can write any amount of storage to its node file system.

For more details how ephemeral storage works please see [Ephemeral Storage Consumption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#resource-emphemeralstorage-consumption).

Comment: thanks @thomas for the reply... In my case, you can see my above screenshot that the machine has enough space so the docker log is not a reason. also we are not using empty{} dir for mounting volume . We have ephemeral-storage limit to 5GB in our pod spec also.